# FreeRTOS starvation and time slicing

Tags: c, embedded, freertos

I got problem with running FreeRTOS on cortex m4 processor. I got 3 tasks: periodic and 2 continous.

```
static const char text1[] = "Periodic task\r\n";
static const char text2[] = "Continous Task\r\n";
static const char text3[] = "Continous Task 2\r\n";

void periodicTask(void *pvParameter)
{
    TickType_t prevCount;
    char *printText = (char*)pvParameter;

    prevCount= xTaskGetTickCount();

    for(;;)
    {
        printf(printText);

        vTaskDelayUntil(&prevCount,pdMS_TO_TICKS(5));
    }
}

void continousTask(void *pvParameter)
{
    char *printText = (char*)pvParameter;

    for(;;)
    {
        printf(printText);
        vTaskDelay(1);
    }
}

int main(void) 
{

    xTaskCreate(periodicTask,"periodic task",200,(void*)text1,3,NULL);
    xTaskCreate(continousTask,"continous task 1",200,(void*)text2,0,NULL);
    //xTaskCreate(continousTask,"continous task 2",200,(void*)text3,0,NULL);


    vTaskStartScheduler();

    while(1)
    {

    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Above code is running just fine but only if i got `vTaskDelay(1)` in continousTask if i remove it my continous task 2 and periodic task will starve(or run not on desired period) which shouldn't take place because periodic task is higher priority. Continous task 2 also shouldn't starve because i got `configUSE_TIME_SLICING 1` defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely cause would be the print statements.  How are they implemented?  If they use semihosting then the scheduler is not going to work properly as there will be hardware conflicts.  If they are not using semihosting then make sure they are blocking writes (by which I mean the task performing the write enters the blocked state, so not using any cpu time and allows the other task to run, while the IO is actually performed).  The free book (https://www.freertos.org/Documentation/RTOS_book.html ) has more on the perils of using printf().